# Build a project without "Makefile.am", just using Autoconf & Autoscan?

Tags: build, makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I recently read that "[There are several ways to configure and build a project using Autotools.](http://www.sax.de/unix-stammtisch/docs/autotools/autotools.html#ways%20to%20use%20autotools)"

**Among them:

Autoconf and Autoscan:**
  - Makefile.in with project build rules and Makefile substitutions
**Autoheader (usable in addition to all other tools)**
  - scans the project and generates a config.h file during project 
    configuration with platform specific macro definitions, no configuration 
    files needed

How do you build a project without "Makefile.am"? Just using Autoconf, Autoscan & maybe Autoheader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the link says, `Makefile.in` is the template for `Makefile` which would just have `@FOO@` macros for `configure` (via `AC_CONFIG_FILES`) to substitute.  If the project is *really* simple, I can imagine it would work OK without `automake`.

All `autoscan` and `autoheader` do is help you build primitive `configure.ac` and `config.h` files for your project.  You aren't required to use *them* either.